# d3.js ／ without using the call method, you can view the x-axis?

Tags: d3.js

**Current code**
/ Call method used

```
var svg = d3.select("#hoge").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 600).attr("height", 400)
var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 100])
    .range([0, 400]);
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .call(d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(xScale)
    );
```

---

**I want to know**
/ Call method unused

```
var svg = d3.select("#hoge").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 600).attr("height", 400)
var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 100])
    .range([0, 400]);
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis");

d3.svg.axis(svg).scale(xScale);
```

---

If you do not use the call method
The x-axis can not be displayed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`d3.svg.axis()` creates and returns a function that appends the SVG elements to display the axis.  It does not actually append anything.  If you don't call the function that is returned, those elements will not be added.  This is a common pattern in d3.js so it is important to understand.

Let's say you create these two variables for the axis function and the axis group element:

```
var axisFunction = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale);
var axisGroup = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis");
```

The following two ways of calling the axis function are equivalent:

```
axisFunction(axisGroup);
axisGroup.call(axisFunction);
```

The `call` syntax exists simply to enable method chaining like you have in your current code example.

> The call operator is identical to invoking a function by hand; but it makes it easier to use method chaining.

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#call

Mike Bostock's article [Towards Reusable Charts](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/) does a good job of explaining this pattern.  The pattern described in the article to create the reusable chart is used for a variety of items in d3.js such as `d3.svg.axis`.